Status of Collatz Conjecture for Negative Integers (a.k.a. $3x-1$ problem)
I was (surprisingly) not able to find online much information about the Collatz Conjecture on the negative integers. We know there are three cycles: $(-1 \rightarrow -2 \rightarrow -1)$, $(-5 \rightarrow -7 \rightarrow -5)$, $(-17 \rightarrow -25 \rightarrow -37 \rightarrow -55 \rightarrow -82 \rightarrow -41 \rightarrow -61 \rightarrow -91 \rightarrow -136 \rightarrow -68 \rightarrow -34 \rightarrow -17)$, but that seems to be the only thing we currently know.
Have there be any verification efforts on this negative part of the problem, or established arguments about hypothetical nontrivial-cycles (e.g. lower bound for their length) or divergent trajectories therein, or any other relevant research?
A similar question specifically about cycles was asked 10 years ago here, to which the answers indicated that there was then indeed such an absence in the literature, and that absence seems to have remained...?

See here, and other posts, e.g., this one. Your posts looks like a copy from reddit.

That second link is a particularly nice question.

Would it be interesting for you to look into one older answer of mine about cycles? See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172476/what-are-possibilities-to-disprove-the-collatz-conjecture/243519#243519 This answer was about the $3x+1$ problem. But you can apply it to $3x-1$ (which equals $3x+1$ in the negative numbers) if you simply do $-1$ instead of $+1$ in the numerators of fractions. The interesting part is here - as I think - some algebraical formula to access the cycle problem and to find some useful and restrictive lower bounds this way.
